# present model view controller orientation?

Tags: iphone

on loading my device is in landscape mode.
my parent view controller is also in lanscape mode 
but the `presentModelViewController:` which I loaded from **nib** file is in potrait mode.

```
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loginIn) withObject:nil];
    loadingAlert = [[LoadingAlert alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingAlert" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loadingAlert];
    [navigationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [navigationController.navigationBar setOpaque:NO];

    [navigationController.navigationBar applyCustomColor];

    UIWindow* keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:NO];
```

it only happens when application runs first time, for other than first time it works fine .

Answer (score 1):

check `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in `LoadingAlert` class, it should be like this if you are supporting all orientations

-

```
 (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

// Return YES for supported orientations

return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use to call Modal view controller with this method

```
[self performSelector:SEL withObject:id afterInterval:time];
```

then the my problem is resolved. dont know how but i think main thread got cycles to make GUI correct.